# Django: How to avoid duplicated html id for showing field twice in the same form?

Tags: python, django

I want to generate the same field twice in the same form, which is useful when there are condition to show 1st textInput or 2nd textInput:
Django will generate:

```
<!--same form -->
<input type="radio" value="good_price"/> <!-- show good price if this is checked　-->
<input type="radio" value="bad_price"/> <!-- show bad price if this is checked　-->

<!--1st -->
Good price <input id="id_name"..../>
<input id="options_with_good_price"/>

<!--2nd -->
Bad Price <input id="id_name".../>
<input id="options_with_bad_price"/>
```

So there are duplicated html id, how to avoid it? (I can survive with no id generated for these two boxes with duplicated id, but not all the others)

Comment: How are you generating this form?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

`{{ form.element }}`

You can do the following:

`{{ form.element|attr:"id:another_name" }}`

---

Sorry didn't realized the template filter i used:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/729/

I just changed `=` by `:`

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, saying "INvalid filters: 'attr'"

Comment: Also works with [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks), same syntax.